# How does this variadic template with using work?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have this code snippet and am trying to understand how it works:

```
#include <iostream>

class GenBase
{
public:
    void BaseClass()
    {
        std::cout << " BaseClass " << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class Base>
class General: public Base
{
    public:
        void PrintGeneral()
        {
            std::cout << " General " << std::endl;
        }
};

template <typename... Types>
struct BaseHelper;

template <typename Type, typename... Types>
struct BaseHelper< Type, Types...>
{
    using BaseType = General<typename BaseHelper<Types... >::BaseType>;
};

template <typename Type>
struct BaseHelper<Type>
{
    using BaseType = General<GenBase>;
};

template <typename... Types>
class OurClass: public BaseHelper<Types...>::BaseType
{
public:
     void print_smth()
     {
        BaseType::PrintGeneral();
     }

private:
     using BaseType = typename BaseHelper<Types...>::BaseType;
};

class Test
{
  public:
      void foo();
};
```

1. `using BaseType = General<typename BaseHelper<Types... >::BaseType>`

   Why do we need `::BaseType` at the end?
2. What type would `BaseType` contain in `OurClass` if we instantiate it with `OurClass<int,float,Test>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `using BaseType = General<typename BaseHelper<Types... >::BaseType>`
>
> Why do we need `::BaseType` at the end?

`General<typename BaseHelper<Types... >` and `General<typename BaseHelper<Types... >::BaseType` are different types; with `::BaseType` you select the `BaseType` defined, through `using`, inside `General<typename BaseHelper<Types... >`

> What type would `BaseType` contain in `OurClass` if we instantiate it with `OurClass<int,float,Test>`?

You get that `BaseType` is defined as `General<General<General<GenBase>>>`.

I'll try to show you, step by step, how to you get that type.

You have `OurClass<int,float,Test>`, so `Types...` is `int, float, Test`, so

```
// 1: Types... is int, float, Test
using BaseType = typename BaseHelper<int, float, Test>::BaseType;
```

Next step: `BaseType` in `BaseHelper<int, float, Test>` (general template selected; `Type` is `int` and `Types...` is `float, Test`) is defined as

```
// 2: Types... is float, Test
using BaseType = General<typename BaseHelper<float, Test>::BaseType>;
```

Next step: `BaseType` in `BaseHelper<float, Test>` (general template selected; `Type` is `float` and `Types...` is `Test`) is defined as

```
// 3: Types... is Test
using BaseType = General<typename BaseHelper<Test>::BaseType>;
```

Next step: `BaseType` in `BaseHelper<Test>` (partial specialization `BaseHelper<Type>`, with `Test` as `Type`, is selected) is defined as

```
// 4
using BaseType = General<GenBase>;
```

Next step: we substitute `General<GenBase>` in 3, so

```
// 3: BaseHelper<Test>::BaseType> is General<GenBase>
using BaseType = General<General<GenBase>>;
```

Next step: we substitute `General<General<GenBase>>` in 2, so

```
// 2: BaseHelper<float, Test>::BaseType is General<General<GenBase>>
using BaseType = General<General<General<GenBase>>>;
```

Final step: we substitute `General<General<General<GenBase>>>` in 1,

```
// 1: BaseHelper<int, float, Test>::BaseType is General<General<General<GenBase>>>
using BaseType = General<General<General<GenBase>>>;
```

Conclusion: `OurClass<int,float,Test>::BaseType` is `General<General<General<GenBase>>>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

1. `General<typename BaseHelper<Types... >::BaseType` access the `using BaseType = General<GenBase>` type, which has access to the `void BaseClass()` function.
2. Using that constructor would call the `BaseHelper <Type, Types...>`, so you would get `BaseHelper` with `Type = int` and `Types = float, Test`, which would make a `General` type with `Types = float, Test`.